# Phonegap without eclipse

Tags: cordova, camera

Is it possible to create Phonegap APP´s without using Eclipse, but using like Notepad++ instead, and still get access to smartphone specifics like camera, accelerometor, sound recorder ect. ?

I did try to create all the needed files like config.xml and index.html and so forth.  But i cant get the Camera to work, i havent tryed other API´s.  I used the Full Example code from Phonegap´s own website under API´s (docs).

Another issue i found was that, i cant find any good web tutorials about Phonegap without using Eclipse.

I hope that my question is clear.  Im not a native english speaker, so sorry for my choice of words.

Best regards

Dan

Comment: you´re developing for which platform? Android?

Comment: I want to develop for all the platforms that Phonegap give the posiblity to do.

Comment: If i understand it correct, if i use Phonegap´s compiling method i dont have to think about which platform i develop for?  It does compile the different Apps for the different platforms.  I dont know if im correct here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do that by either building your project from the command line using ant or a service like build.phonegap.com.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install -g cordova` will give you a neat command line interface.

See also https://npmjs.org/package/cordova

```
cordova create Baz
cd Baz
cordova platform add android
cordova build
cordova compile android # will install the .apk on your connected Android device
```

Just not sure how this plays out in Windows but Node.js and `npm` seem to be available so it should be fine. If you run into problems you might want to try cygwin. (Personally it's been first thing to install if I ever have to do something serious on Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

I only use Eclipse to launch the debugger and export the apk package. I edit the project files directly with SublimeText. It works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which platform you are targeting. Phonegap is just a Javascript to native API library wrapper over your HTML web container. You can refer to this post for clearer understanding:

[Phonegap Explained Visually](http://phonegap.com/2012/05/02/phonegap-explained-visually/)

For Android, you will need Eclipse to compile the app and also download the Android emulators for various versions (2.1,2.2,.., 4.1) . For iOS, you will need xCode to compile the app and also the iPhone/iPad emulators. The build service offered by PhoneGap (build.phonegap.com) simplified this process by compiling your code in the server and gives you back the binaries.

If you are using Google Chrome to test a Phonegap app, take note that you can only simulate the UI and web services. You will not be able to test the phone specific features such as camera, accelerometer because the web browser does not have such features.

Comment: Not entirely true - eclipse only automates the tools mentioned. There's nothing to stop you invoking the various compilers manually although it would be a real pain in the backside

Comment: yep I mean Eclipse is an IDE just like xCode. It makes the job easier. We can always use command line tools to compile the code directly. But I think Daniel was probably looking for an easy way as he is quite new to PhoneGap or Android.

Comment: As i understand it, when i choose to compile my app with phonehap, it do compile the different apps for the different platforms, as you guys are saying it, it almost sounds like that the Iphone app for ex. that phonegap compiles dosent work on an iphone?

Im forced to use Phonehap´s online services by uploading either a Zip file or to use Dreamweaver as a gateway to Phonegap, either is fine.

I recently tested with Dreamweaver and i got it to work.  I got a little app running on my android phone atm, that gives me the location where i am, and puts it in a google map.